# Is there a formula in Excel that can parse this bank statement info into 5 columns?

Tags: excel, parsing

I'm sure someone has this already figured out, does anyone know an efficient way to parse this bank statement data into 5 columns (PostDate, TransDate, Description, Reference, Amount)?

```
01/04 01/03 FREEMAN LAS VEGAS 702-263-1404 NV 24692168003100699831031 790.36
01/05 01/04 ACCESSLINE *PHONE SVC 877-880-0055 WA 24692168004100168682146 80.09
01/05 01/04 GOOGLE *Google Store g.co/helppay#CA 24692168004100168978023 439.30
01/02 01/01 Online scheduled payment 00106005710045808719965 - 3,000.00
01/03 01/03 PAYMENT - THANK YOU 00383204320010300053151 - 710.76
01/05 01/05 PURCHASE *FINANCE CHARGE* 324.06
01/05 01/05 PURCHASE *FINANCE CHARGE* 116.20
01/22 01/21 Online payment from CHK 4 02106005720005589584883 - 4,000.00
02/01 02/01 Online scheduled payment 03206005720022488600832 - 3,000.00
02/01 02/01 PAYMENT - THANK YOU 03283204320020100053181 - 818.73
02/07 02/07 PURCHASE *FINANCE CHARGE* 314.90
02/07 02/07 PURCHASE *FINANCE CHARGE* 115.78
01/08 01/04 ITN CONFERENCE SVCS 999-9999999 UT 24121578005000004040105 70.00
01/08 01/06 MOBILESPHERESLYDIAL 617-399-9980 MA 24492158006719966344160 2.95
01/12 01/11 APL* ITUNES.COM/BILL 866-712-7753 CA 24692168011100545777669 8.80
```

Comment: Do you know if the actual data only has spaces in it, or is is possible it is tab separated? If it is you can parse it using import functionality, if not you will probably need to write a script to parse it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kevin... Yes, it has spaces, but since there are spaces between the columns, but also, within the Description and Reference columns, I can't go off of that alone.

Comment: Right that is the problem then. Do you have any experience writing vba code? This could be accomplished quite easily with that.

Comment: Do you know an easy function to grab the RIGHT text until the first Space? (unless the next character is a hyphen as that denotes a negative amount and there is a space between the Amount and the hyphen.
Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, not versed in VBA. Rookie here.
But, I think I'll be okay. I can figure out how to grab the RIGHT up to the space, and then spot-check for the negatives. That still saves me hours!

Comment: The irregularity of your data makes this very complicated. You got missing references, some extra dashes, etc. No true pattern to work with. To be honest, I think your best bet will be `VBA` and a plunge into `Regular Expressions`. And otherwise try text-to-columns and split by space and see if you can work with that. There are also plenty examples on formulas around to try and grap the last "word" of a string.

Comment: Thanks Kevin & JvdV - this was my first post here, you two were very helpful, and I know how to proceed so, Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shane if you want to learn so vba I wrote some code for you. If you place your cursor on a line in the spreadsheet it will paste in the values for you. If you have any questions let us know.

```
Sub SplitTransaction()

Dim trans As String
Dim lastSpace As Integer
Dim PostDate, TransDate, Description, Reference, Amount
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":" & ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Address)

For Each cell In rng


    'set the transactiond data to the active cell
    trans = cell.Value

    'parse out the post date and trim off
    PostDate = Left(trans, 5)
    trans = Mid(trans, 7)

    'parse out the trans date and trim off
    TransDate = Left(trans, 5)
    trans = Mid(trans, 7)

    'get the amount and trim off
    lastSpace = InStrRev(trans, " ") + 1
    Amount = Mid(trans, lastSpace)
    trans = Left(trans, lastSpace - 2)

    'check for a negative and apply and trim
    If Right(trans, 1) = "-" Then
        Amount = Amount * -1
        trans = Left(trans, Len(trans) - 2)
    End If

    'get the reference, if the reference is missing then exclude
    lastSpace = InStrRev(trans, " ") + 1

    Reference = Mid(trans, lastSpace)

    If IsNumeric(Reference) And Len(Reference) > 10 Then 'we have a valid reference
        Description = Left(trans, lastSpace - 2)
    Else
        Reference = ""
        Description = trans
    End If

    'PostDate, TransDate, Description, Reference, Amount
    'paste the values
    cell.Offset(, 1).Value = PostDate
    cell.Offset(, 2).Value = TransDate
    cell.Offset(, 3).Value = Description
    cell.Offset(, 4).NumberFormat = "@"
    cell.Offset(, 4).Value = Reference
    cell.Offset(, 5).Value = Amount

Next cell

End Sub
```

[image: Excel Parse Data]

Comment: Wow Kevin!
I don't know what to say, Thank You so much for your time and effort. And, now you gave me the nudge I needed to dig into VBA a little bit. This is so cool... it's 4am in Seattle and I'm still cranking away at this, and I know this code will save me so much time, Thank you, thank you!

Comment: BTW - It works perfectly! Not a single error - even though I'm working with seemingly disparate data. Amazing work, very clean, and Thank You again!

And, until I figure out how to do a loop, check out my hack... I created a giant button so I could down-arrow, click, down-arrow, click, rinse and repeat.
I didn't know how to make the Excel Module 'Active' for me to simply click in the field. If you can let me know, otherwise I'll use the button for now.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1815KsRlF0ap2w3l4VwVANvn-OgF3V1AX

Comment: There are several things you could do. It really depends on the data you are working with. I'll add a little code to show you how to start at the current cell and run until a blank cell is encountered. Great job (also please accept this as the answer if you like it)!

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done in Power Query (Get & Transform) without writing any code. Use several separate ribbon commands to split the data by the space delimiter for the first two columns. Since the data format unfortunately separates the negative sign with a space as well, you need to use a few IF conditions to work out the number value, but all this can be done with ribbon commands and simple formulas.

It is repeatable and the data can be loaded straight from the CSV file.

The beauty of Power Query is that it is easy to understand what steps are applied if they need changing. VBA code is so much more complex and harder to maintain.

Comment: Thank you Teylyn, I'll definitely have a look at this too. Thankfully, Kevin has finished the VBA and so this might be taken care of, but I like the idea of loading straight from the CSV file.
Thanks, and I'll check this suggestion out, I appreciate your response!
-Shane

Comment: @teylyn - There is always more than one way to accomplish things. This could also be done using just formulas, but I would find that unruly. I like the VBA method and it could easily be adapted to read from a CSV.

Comment: @Kevin You sound a tad defensive. I'm just pointing out alternatives to writing code. A lot of people ask for or write VBA because they're not aware of what Power Query can do with just a few clicks.